# Reset the initial state value in Recat Native

Tags: react-native

**Requirement:** I have to blink a View for 2 sec with 2 different color (for ex red and white).
I can do this by using this code -

```
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(false)
    const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState(0)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (initialState < 2){
            let interval = setInterval(() => {
                setState(true)
                setInitialState(initialState + 1)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setState(false)
                }, 80);
            }, 300);
            setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(interval)
            }, 600);
        }
    }, [initialState])
```

and called it like -

```
<View style={{...styles.mainContainer, backgroundColor: state ? Colors.GRO7 : Colors.GRC9}}>
```

**Another Requirement:** I have another screen from it i an change the address, on successful address change i have to blink this view again for 2 sec. I'm not sure where i can reset the initial value to 0 again.

I am new In react native, could some one guide me how to achieve this functionality

Comment: Do you want to blink your view after every 2 second ? if yes, then how will the view behave after address change?

Answer (score 0):

Can‘t completely understand what‘s your target.

Here is a blinking text [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/blinking-text)

Comment: doing the same but how could I stop it in two blink only and how could i start it again once screen gets apear again ?

Comment: in your case its going for infinite blinking but i have to stop it after two blink, could you help?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass in the initial value to this component instead of defining 0 in this line:

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState(0)
```

you could have a param to pass in and put it instead of `0` so that every time that param changes this component will re render. and so you get a new initial state.
for example:

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState(initialValue)
```